# Can I use double question mark to lookup documentation in Kaggle kernals Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kaggle

## Intro

In a standard Jupyter notebook, I could use the double question mark `??` to lookup documentation of a function or library etc. For example, if I do this in Jupyter notebook locally on my laptop (import numpy and lookup its documentation):

```
import numpy as np
??np
```

the note book would print out the numpy documentation (that looks something like this):

```
Type:        module
String form: <module 'numpy' from '/Users/johnny/anaconda/envs/fastai36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py'>
File:        ~/anaconda/envs/fastai36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py
Source:     
"""
NumPy
=====

Provides
  1. An array object of arbitrary homogeneous items
  2. Fast mathematical operations over arrays
  3. Linear Algebra, Fourier Transforms, Random Number Generation

etc...
```

I notice that when I do the same thing in a Kaggle notebook, nothing happens.

## The question

1. is it possible to use the `??` to lookup documentation via Kaggle Jupyter Notebook?
2. is the Kaggle Jupyter notebook implemented differently to a normal Jupyter notebook? (For example, I notice block indent works on normal notebook, but not Kaggle Notebook).
3. are there documentations around Kaggle Kernals Jupyter Notebook?

Many thanks indeed.

Answer (score 2):

I had no problems doing that, but look you need to select a function, not the package itself.

[image]