# Jupyter notebook question mark doesn't display anything

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

I have a jupyter notebook and this is in a cell:

```
plt.figure?
```

Nothing is being displayed and I'm not sure why. Doing a google search, it seems like some people have had similar issues and have attributed it to an iPython error. I am currently on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

Comment: That's not proper Python syntax and so if you are using a Python kernel in your Jupyter notebook, then I don't see why you wouldn't be getting an error? But you say nothing is displayed? Is it actually in a code cell or markdown? In other words, what is the context? We cannot tell much on the little you provided. Then you say: "Doing a google search, it seems like some people have had similar issues and have attributed it to an iPython error", but don't provide any such details supporting what you are saying. Where are such posts? And then this circles back to the lack of information...

Comment: <continued>  about your issue: do you see an IPython error? Did something happen before and is now not happening? Are you expecting details about the code yet you haven't completed the function syntax? Did you try `plt.figure(?`? (I didn't try that yet myself & so I don't know if I should be putting both parentheses or none to get the help information to come up.) Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36226945/8508004) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55938433/8508004) an example? Have you tried what you say in the IPython console/interpreter & then seen what happens and then try Jupyter?

Comment: @Wayne It was part of a ipynb file given to me by my professor. I should have mentioned that we were using Matplotlib. I tried running the cell again and it opened in another window.

Comment: So it is all good?

Comment: @Wayne yes. It is all good.